# primitive promotion for >> [Java]

Tags: java, primitive-types, promotions

I encountered misunderstanding of primitive promotion in the next code snippet.

```
byte a = 2;
int b = a >> 4L;
```

*What would I expect?*

`long b = (int)a >> 4L;`
`long b = a >> 4L;`
<strike>`int b = a >> 4L;`</strike>

`int >> long` will promote to the larger data type (`long`) and it won't compile with resulted `int` type.

*What have I received?*

It compiles fine. **Why?**

Comment: The widening rules take no notice of the binary operation, only the widest operand e.g. `x % (byte) b` cannot possibly be wider than a `byte` and yet it never is a `byte`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JLS won't "promote to the larger datatype" here, because it does not perform binary numeric promotion for shifting operators.  This is covered by the [JLS, Section 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19).

> Unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) is performed on each operand separately. (Binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is *not* performed on the operands.)

Unary numeric promotion promotes the byte `a` to an `int`.  The literal `4L` is not changed, but it only needs to be a integral type anyway.

> It is a compile-time error if the type of each of the operands of a shift operator, after unary numeric promotion, is not a primitive integral type.

Then for the shifting, only the least 5 significant bits are used to shift an `int`.

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, then only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

The result of the operator is an `int`, not a `long`, so it can be assigned to an `int` without a compiler error.

> The type of the shift expression is the promoted type of the left-hand operand.

Answer (score 1):

By the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> The type of the shift expression is the promoted type of the left-hand operand.

The right-hand operand of a shift operator doesn't have any effect on the expression's type. Unlike with an operator like `+`, a bigger type on the right doesn't mean the result could be any bigger or any smaller.